# Query Active Directory Groups With Additional Properties

Tags: c#, .net, f#, active-directory, ldap

I can query my Active Directory groups with the following:

```
open System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

let specialGroups () =
    let ctx = new PrincipalContext(
                contextType = ContextType.Domain, 
                name = "domain.net", 
                container = "DC=domain,DC=net")
    let allGroups = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, "*")
    let srch = new PrincipalSearcher(allGroups)
    [| for group in srch.FindAll() -> group |]
```

How can I add certain properties, like Mail, like this PowerShell does?

```
Get-ADGroup "GROUPNAME.UG" -Properties Mail
```

Comment: this isn't C#, right?

Comment: anyway, this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload) might be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the properties by retrieving the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object, then accessing its `Properties` collection.  Here's an example defining a `getProperty` function for the `Principal` object, then using it to filter on the `"Mail"` property:

```
open System.DirectoryServices
open System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

    let getProperty name (group: Principal) =
    let entry = group.GetUnderlyingObject() |> unbox<DirectoryEntry>
    [| for value in entry.Properties.[name] -> value |> string |]

let specialGroups () =
    let ctx = new PrincipalContext(
                contextType = ContextType.Domain, 
                name = "domain.net", 
                container = "DC=domain,DC=net")
    let allGroups = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, "*")
    let srch = new PrincipalSearcher(allGroups)
    [| for group in srch.FindAll() |> Seq.filter (getProperty "Mail" >> Array.isEmpty) -> group |]
```